# What's the equivalent to 'rm -rf' with Windows command?

Tags: windows-7

I need to delete a whole directory (with a lot of sub directories and files) by running a command in a batch file.

I tried delete and erase, but both of them requires me to answer 'Y/N', and it doesn't seem to delete the directories if one has subdirectories or files.

What command can I use to delete a directory with subdirectories/files without whatever prompt?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
rmdir /s /q [directory]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
DEL /Q /S /F <FILE/DIR>
```

or

```
DELETE /Q /S /F <FILE/DIR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a valid command in the W7 CLI, but back when DOS was still DOS, it was as simple as:

```
deltree /y <dirname or path>
```

Comment: deltree is not supported in Win7.